# Is this Canon setup good enough for amateur photography?

Tags: lens, canon, amateur

So I am about to buy my Canon EOS 70D which will be used both for amateur photography and video. Since I am going to do a lot of traveling this year I want to cover as many kinds of lenses as possible.

For wide shots I want to buy **Canon 10-18mm f/4.5-5.6**. I know that aperture isn't that good but most of the wide shots will be made outdoors and IS will add some f-stops as well. It is also very cheap.

For a street shots (normal) I will be using **Canon 35mm f/2 IS STM** lens.

Last but not least is the portrait lens. I was thinking about **Canon 50mm f/1.4** or **Canon 85mm f/1.8**. The price is almost the same but from what I've heard the 85mm f/1.8 will be better for portrait without getting too close to the person.

Do you have any suggestions or should I just stick with this setup?

Comment: "Good enough" isn't a question we can answer. Good enough for what?

Comment: "Amateur photography" means nothing, at least in terms of what kind of gear is "good enough".

Comment: What kind of photography will you be doing ? Please mention that

Comment: Just as I described - landscapes/architecture, family portraits and thats it.

Comment: I'll just say that all [those](https://500px.com/fkraiem) were taken for less money than the 70D body alone.

Comment: @fkraiem Wow, that's a really nice collection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general they would be fine. Although I would suggest getting a more do it all zoom first, even the kit lens. I suggest this for two reasons 1) a zoom is more flexible, you can use it a bit, then see what focal lengths you are using. 2) I find 1 zoom lens easier when travelling, due to being lighter and more compact than a bag full of primes plus you won't need to keep changing lenses.

I'd suggest a telephoto lens as a good addition, the Canon 55-250 is meant to give good bang per buck, although I haven't used it.

Of the lenses you suggested I'll offer some feedback:

**Canon 10-18mm f/4.5-5.6** - This is a very wide lens, and images taken with such wide lenses can all look very similar. Vertical lines in your arcitecture images could be off vertical for example.

**Canon 35mm f/2 IS STM** - I think this would be a good first prime lens on a 70D.

**Canon 50mm f/1.4** - I have this lens, and would actually suggest saving some money and looking at the Canon 50mm f/1.8 STM instead, especially as you mention video in your requirements. The f1.4 version is quite a fragile lens, and only a fraction faster.

**Canon 85mm f/1.8** - I regularly use this lens and it is good for outdoor portaits on a cropped sensor camera.

Comment: Thank you for your input. I was also thinking about replacing 10-18 and 35 with 17-55 F2.8. It costs the same as the other two together. What i'm worried about is the 2.8 apperture and that 17mm may not be wide enough for crop. What do you think about it?

Comment: I found 17mm wide enough for me on a cropped sensor body. The 17-55 f2.8 is a good lens, but my recommendation is to get the camera and a cheaper lens, then you can find out what works for your particular needs.

Comment: I once had 70d with 18-135 is stm but had to sell It due to some financial problems. I also had 50mm 1.4 as my prime but I had to get very far with it so I think 35mm will work much beter for me. I think I'll stick with It and the others I mentioned because they cover my needs so far.

Comment: Ok, if you've got some knowledge of what works for you that changes things. 35mm does work better as a standard lens on a cropped sensor camera.

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing what kind of photography your into (although you have specified the purpose behind every lens) I'd go ahead and say **yes**!

I would've killed for the Canon 35mm f/2 IS STM and the 50mm f/1.4 when I first started out. Now in my own opinion, I think you'll be running around using the 35mm pretty much all the time, but i guess the 10-18mm could help you for some real wide landscapes or similar work, and as you said the 50mm/85mm for portraits. Sidenote! You'll probably not feel "too close" with the 50mm on a cropped sensor camera as the 70D, it's a pretty nice range for portraits in my opinion, especially if you 're indoors, which means space might be an issue.

One of my tips would be checking out the Canon 24mm f/2.8 EF-S, and replacing the 35mm and 10-18mm in the beginning. It's a great all around lens! (And it's dirt cheap).

Comment: At this very moment I'm into landscapes/architecture and family photography. Just to share with my family and friends. Nothing more than that.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to care much about aperture for an ultra-wide lens:

- A short focal length will anyway give you a very deep **depth of field**. Don't hope you'll be able to get a nice smooth bokeh with a short lens.
- **Motion blur** is rarely an issue with ultra-wide: you'd need to move a lot to get a visible motion blur. It's very easy to get sharp shots at 1/10s with this kind of lens.

Most pictures I take with an ultra-wide are outdoor shots, and if you are planning the same then aperture will never be an issue. I can imagine f/4.5 being limiting for low-light indoor shots OTOH.